# Arch Linux can't find CUDA?

Tags: python, linux, archlinux

I'm trying to get StableTuner working on Arch Linux and while I've gotten far I'm currently facing a problem now when I run the .sh file used for training.

I'm getting this error when trying to run StableTuner:

```
[campfire@archlinux scripts]$ bash run.sh
 Booting Up StableTuner
 Please wait a moment as we load up some stuff...
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py:231: FutureWarning: `logging_dir` is deprecated and will be removed in version 0.18.0 of  Accelerate. Use `project_dir` instead.
  warnings.warn(
You are using a model of type clip_text_model to instantiate a model of type . This is not supported for all configurations of models and can yield errors.

===================================BUG REPORT===================================
Welcome to bitsandbytes. For bug reports, please submit your error trace to: https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues
For effortless bug reporting copy-paste your error into this form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScPB8emS3Thkp66nvqwmjTEgxp8Y9ufuWTzFyr9kJ5AoI47dQ/viewform?usp=sf_link
================================================================================
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cuda_setup/paths.py:27: UserWarning: WARNING: The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {PosixPath('@/tmp/.ICE-unix/582,unix/archlinux'), PosixPath('local/archlinux')}
  warn(
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cuda_setup/paths.py:27: UserWarning: WARNING: The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {PosixPath('/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0')}
  warn(
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cuda_setup/paths.py:27: UserWarning: WARNING: The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {PosixPath('/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0')}
  warn(
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cuda_setup/paths.py:27: UserWarning: WARNING: The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {PosixPath('//debuginfod.archlinux.org '), PosixPath('https')}
  warn(
CUDA_SETUP: WARNING! libcudart.so not found in any environmental path. Searching /usr/local/cuda/lib64...
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cuda_setup/paths.py:27: UserWarning: WARNING: The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {PosixPath('/usr/local/cuda/lib64')}
  warn(
WARNING: No libcudart.so found! Install CUDA or the cudatoolkit package (anaconda)!
CUDA SETUP: Loading binary /home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cpu.so...
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cextension.py:48: UserWarning: The installed version of bitsandbytes was compiled without GPU support. 8-bit optimizers and GPU quantization are unavailable.
  warn(
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/configuration_utils.py:195: FutureWarning: It is deprecated to pass a pretrained model name or path to `from_config`.If you were trying to load a scheduler, please use <class 'diffusers.schedulers.scheduling_ddpm.DDPMScheduler'>.from_pretrained(...) instead. Otherwise, please make sure to pass a configuration dictionary instead. This functionality will be removed in v1.0.0.
  deprecate("config-passed-as-path", "1.0.0", deprecation_message, standard_warn=False)
 Creating Auto Bucketing Dataloader
  Rounded resolution to: 512
  Preloading images...
  ** Processing /home/campfire/Desktop: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 3562.34it/s]
 ** Number of buckets: 2
  ** Bucket (512, 512) found 1 images, will duplicate 34 images due to batch size 35
  ** Bucket (640, 384) found 2 images, will duplicate 33 images due to batch size 35
  Number of image-caption pairs: 70

  ** Validation Set: val, steps: 2, repeats: 1 

 Generating latents cache...
Caching latents: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:08<00:00,  4.17s/it]
 Latents are ready.
  0%|                                                                                                                                               | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s Starting Training!%|                                                                                                                              | 0/200 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Fetching 15 files: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 15/15 [00:00<00:00, 28728.11it/s]
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/feature_extraction_clip.py:28: FutureWarning: The class CLIPFeatureExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in version 5 of Transformers. Please use CLIPImageProcessor instead.
  warnings.warn(s:   0%|                                                                                                                           | 0/15 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
You have disabled the safety checker for <class 'diffusers.pipelines.stable_diffusion.pipeline_stable_diffusion.StableDiffusionPipeline'> by passing `safety_checker=None`. Ensure that you abide to the conditions of the Stable Diffusion license and do not expose unfiltered results in services or applications open to the public. Both the diffusers team and Hugging Face strongly recommend to keep the safety filter enabled in all public facing circumstances, disabling it only for use-cases that involve analyzing network behavior or auditing its results. For more information, please have a look at https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/pull/254 .
Steps To Epoch:   0%|                                                                                                                               | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/campfire/StableTuner/scripts/scripts/trainer.py", line 2738, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/campfire/StableTuner/scripts/scripts/trainer.py", line 2613, in main
    model_pred = unet(noisy_latents, timesteps, encoder_hidden_states).sample
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/utils/operations.py", line 489, in __call__
    return convert_to_fp32(self.model_forward(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/amp/autocast_mode.py", line 14, in decorate_autocast
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/unet_2d_condition.py", line 424, in forward
    sample, res_samples = downsample_block(
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/unet_2d_blocks.py", line 770, in forward
    hidden_states = torch.utils.checkpoint.checkpoint(
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py", line 249, in checkpoint
    return CheckpointFunction.apply(function, preserve, *args)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py", line 107, in forward
    outputs = run_function(*args)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/unet_2d_blocks.py", line 763, in custom_forward
    return module(*inputs, return_dict=return_dict)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/attention.py", line 216, in forward
    hidden_states = block(hidden_states, encoder_hidden_states=encoder_hidden_states, timestep=timestep)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/attention.py", line 490, in forward
    hidden_states = self.attn1(norm_hidden_states, attention_mask=attention_mask) + hidden_states
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/attention.py", line 638, in forward
    hidden_states = self._attention(query, key, value, attention_mask)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/attention.py", line 654, in _attention
    attention_scores = torch.baddbmm(
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 8.75 GiB (GPU 0; 23.65 GiB total capacity; 13.25 GiB already allocated; 7.24 GiB free; 13.74 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
Steps To Epoch:   0%|                                                                                                                               | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Overall Steps:   0%|                                                                                                                              | 0/200 [00:02<?, ?it/s]
Overall Epochs:   0%|                                                                                                                             | 0/100 [00:02<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/campfire/.local/bin/accelerate", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/accelerate_cli.py", line 45, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 1097, in launch_command
    simple_launcher(args)
  File "/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 552, in simple_launcher
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=process.returncode, cmd=cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', 'scripts/trainer.py', '--attention=xformers', '--model_variant=base', '--disable_cudnn_benchmark', '--use_text_files_as_captions', '--sample_step_interval=500', '--pretrained_model_name_or_path=runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5', '--pretrained_vae_name_or_path=', '--output_dir=output/new_model', '--seed=3434554', '--resolution=512', '--train_batch_size=35', '--num_train_epochs=100', '--mixed_precision=fp16', '--use_bucketing', '--aspect_mode=dynamic', '--aspect_mode_action_preference=add', '--use_8bit_adam', '--gradient_checkpointing', '--gradient_accumulation_steps=1', '--learning_rate=3e-6', '--lr_warmup_steps=0', '--lr_scheduler=constant', '--regenerate_latent_cache', '--train_text_encoder', '--token_limit=75', '--concepts_list=stabletune_concept_list.json', '--num_class_images=200', '--save_every_n_epoch=100', '--n_save_sample=1', '--sample_height=512', '--sample_width=512', '--dataset_repeats=1', '--sample_on_training_start']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I was told this is due to the CUDA path not being defined and that I needed to set
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`in the .sh or before I run the program in terminal, however inside /opt/ there isn't a CUDA folder.
I already have CUDA installed with pytorch(as it was a requirement) inside the "ST" conda env.

```
torch                    1.13.1+cu116
torchaudio               0.13.1+cu116
torchmetrics             0.11.1
torchvision              0.14.1+cu116
```

When I enter `pip show torch` I get a location of Location: `/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages` I am assuming since the pytorch version came with cu116 that that is where I need to point the path to?
How would I solve this issue? Do I need to point the CUDA PATH to the "ST" conda env instead?

Comment: Did you even read the error output. You are running out of GPU memory

Comment: Yes and I know that to be false since I ran this perfectly fine on windows with the exact same settings. The problem is with CUDA (or bitsandbytes not being able to locate cuda since bitsandbytes lowers the amount of vram you need to train)

Comment: No really it isn’t. You are running out of memory.

Comment: So we are just going to ignore `WARNING: No libcudart.so found! Install CUDA or the cudatoolkit package (anaconda)!
CUDA SETUP: Loading binary /home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cpu.so...
/home/campfire/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cextension.py:48: UserWarning: The installed version of bitsandbytes was compiled without GPU support. 8-bit optimizers and GPU quantization are unavailable.
  warn(` ?

Answer (score 2):

you need to install `cuda` from `sudo pacman -S cuda`. Then you will have /opt/cuda. This is assuming you are on arch linux considering the arch linux tag on the post.  The `cuda` package provides cuda-toolkit, cuda-sdk, and other  libraries that you require.

Comment: Just to add, if you already got cuda another way, such as conda, or some driver install script, you can just add the "overwrite" option to pacman to deal with the conflict. At least, I think so.